# Why i am getting this error message in AWS workspace creation if i have created the bundle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

```
ErrorCode': 'ResourceNotFound.Bundle', 'ErrorMessage': 'The Bundle cannot be used with the current Directory configuration'}, {'WorkspaceRequest': {'DirectoryId': 'd-dsfdcdcdscd', 'UserName': 'userXX', 'BundleId': 'wsb-bjwbetyensa', 'UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled': False, 'RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled': False, 'WorkspaceProperties': {'RunningMode': 'AUTO_STOP', 'RunningModeAutoStopTimeoutInMinutes': 120, 'RootVolumeSizeGib': 80, 'UserVolumeSizeGib': 50}, 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Automation', 'Value': 'Managed'}, {'Key': 'DirectoryGroup', 'Value': 'AWS-Workspaces-uu-4x16'}]}, 'ErrorCode': 'ResourceNotFound.Bundle', 'ErrorMessage': 'The Bundle cannot be used with the current Directory configuration'}]
type here
```

I have created the bundle from another site we have this is a new site in a different region.